# How to find users position by it's value, where in a single position may have multiple users

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, cakephp

```
$users = [
['user_id' => 2,  'total_votes' => 5],
['user_id' => 3,  'total_votes' => 5],
['user_id' => 12, 'total_votes' => 3],
['user_id' => 4,  'total_votes' => 2],
['user_id' => 8,  'total_votes' => 2],
['user_id' => 1,  'total_votes' => 1],
['user_id' => 5,  'total_votes' => 1],
['user_id' => 6,  'total_votes' => 1],
['user_id' => 7,  'total_votes' => 1],
['user_id' => 9,  'total_votes' => 0],
['user_id' => 10, 'total_votes' => 0],
['user_id' => 11, 'total_votes' =>''],
];

$no_of_pos = 3;
```

I've this two variables. And I need to get the following array. What is the best way to get that? Here the $no_of_pos is required positions. So, here I need 1st, 2nd & 3rd and the others will into a new array.

```
$results = [
1 => [
            ['user_id' => 2,  'total_votes' => 5],
            ['user_id' => 3,  'total_votes' => 5],
       ],
2 => [
            ['user_id' => 12, 'total_votes' => 3],
       ],
3 => [
            ['user_id' => 4,  'total_votes' => 2],
            ['user_id' => 8,  'total_votes' => 2],
       ],
'others' => [
            ['user_id' => 1,  'total_votes' => 1],
            ['user_id' => 5,  'total_votes' => 1],
            ['user_id' => 6,  'total_votes' => 1],
            ['user_id' => 7,  'total_votes' => 1],
            ['user_id' => 9,  'total_votes' => 0],
            ['user_id' => 10, 'total_votes' => 0],
            ['user_id' => 11, 'total_votes' =>''],
       ],   
];
```

Now I'm doing as follows

```
$results = array();
$last_vote = isset($users[0]['total_votes']) ? $users[0]['total_votes']: 0;
$pos = 1;

foreach ($users as $user) {
if ($last_vote != $user['total_votes']) {
    $last_vote = $user['total_votes'];
    $pos++;
}

if ($pos <= $no_of_pos) {
    $results[$pos][] = $user;
} else {
    $results['others'][] = $user;
}
}
```

// Additionally, if I want to get as follows, then how can I do that?

```
$results = [
0 => [
            ['user_id' => 2,  'total_votes' => 5],
            ['user_id' => 3,  'total_votes' => 5],
       ],
1 => [
            ['user_id' => 12, 'total_votes' => 3],
       ],
2 => [
            ['user_id' => 4,  'total_votes' => 2],
            ['user_id' => 8,  'total_votes' => 2],
       ],
3 => [
            ['user_id' => 1,  'total_votes' => 1],
            ['user_id' => 5,  'total_votes' => 1],
            ['user_id' => 6,  'total_votes' => 1],
            ['user_id' => 7,  'total_votes' => 1],
     ],
4 => [
            ['user_id' => 9,  'total_votes' => 0],
            ['user_id' => 10, 'total_votes' => 0],
            ['user_id' => 11, 'total_votes' =>''],
       ],   
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CakePHP, the Hash class is your friend.

First we fix the users array:

```
//the empty value will cause trouble. We set it to 0
$users = Hash::map($users, "{n}", function ($array){
    if(empty($array['total_votes'])) $array['total_votes']=0;
    return $array;
});
```

First Part

```
$no_of_pos = 3;

$score=array_flip(Hash::extract($users,'{n}.total_votes'))[$no_of_pos];

$top_results = Hash::combine($users, "{n}[total_votes>=$score].user_id","{n}[total_votes>=$score]","{n}[total_votes>=$score].total_votes");
$other_results=Hash::extract(Hash::combine($users, "{n}[total_votes<$score].user_id","{n}[total_votes<$score]","{n}[total_votes<$score].total_votes"),'{n}.{n}');
$results=array_values(array_merge($top_results,[$other_results]));
```

Second Part

```
$results=array_values(Hash::combine($users, "{n}.user_id","{n}","{n}.total_votes"));
```

Comment: I was searching this type of solution. Really, I've learn something from you. Great! Thanks.

Comment: Great! I've fixed the syntax. For some reason I failed to copy/paste it well.

Comment: The second part is working perfectly. But the first part is not working. Can you please check that?